# How to fix React Native ScrollView default at bottom

Tags: reactjs, react-native, scrollview, chat, native-base

I'm trying to build a `Chat App` with `React Native`.

In the chat screen, there is a `ScrollView` for every message sent and received.

However, every time when I leave the screen and back in, the default of the `ScrollView` is at the top. I've written a function to scrollToEnd after rendered, but that is **After Rendered**, I need to set the `ScrollView` at the bottom **before it actually shows**.

#### I've tried (but users can see it scrolling as soon as it is rendered):

```
const scrollToBottom = () => {
    scrollEl.current.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth'})
}

useEffect(() => {
    scrollToBottom()
}, [scrollEl, loading, chatHistory])

return(
    <ScrollView bottom={0} w="100%" bg="blueGray.100" inverted>
        <VStack flex={1} w="100%" id="VStack">
            {!loading && chatHistory.chats[roomId] && chatHistory.chats[roomId].length > 0 && chatHistory.chats[roomId].map((chat, index) =>
                <ChatItem type={chat.type}
                    text={chat.text}
                    fromSelf={chat.fromSelf}
                    key={index}
                />
            )}
            <Box ref={scrollEl} />
        </VStack>                
    </ScrollView>
)
```

#### I've tried:

- Set `scale: -1` at `CSS`, which actually invert the whole screen upside down.
- Thus, I have to invert every single message to invert them back to the normal side.
- Meanwhile, the scrolling is totally in the opposite way when you scroll by mouse or slide on the screen.

#### Any solutions or suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hardly recommend you to use FlatList cause of the performance of the rendering list
https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist

Also in FlatList you can achieve what exactly you want

https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#initialscrollindex

Even if you want better performance below library handle list better than FlatList
https://github.com/Flipkart/recyclerlistview

Comment: TBH, this is something similar with set `scale(-1)` in `CSS`, which I have to reverse the chat history order in the opposite way, but it does work somehow. Thanks for your answer and doc links!

Comment: Meanwhile, adding this `contentContainerStyle={{ flexDirection: 'column-reverse' }}` does reverse the order, but the time and space complexity would increase much which would cause lagency in loading since there are a lot of messages.

Comment: @JoshLiu true flatlist have inverted prop too https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#inverted
what if you reverse your data? data.reverse()

Comment: @ AE0011 Thank you for your advise, I've finally applied your suggestions of using `FlatList`. However, I changed the logic of storing messages from `array.push()` into `array.unshift()`.